# Counting decimal places using Excel gives weird result

Tags: excel

I am trying to count the decimal places using a simple formula `=LEN(A1-INT(A1))-2`. The cell `A1` is formated as `Standard` and contains e.g. the value `100.000739`.

I don't understand why the formula returns 18 instead of 6?

```
=A1-INT(A1)               ==> returns 0.000739 which is fine
=LEN(A1-INT(A1))-2        ==> returns 18 
=LEN(0.000739)            ==> returns 8 which is fine
```

Even if I explicitly formate the cell as a numer having 6 decimal places the formula still returns 18. Any idea?

---

Used version `Microsoft Excel 2013`

Comment: What are you trying to do? LEN is for measuring the length of strings. This is probably an artefact of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: And that's why `=LEN(TEXT(A1-INT(A1),"Standard"))-2` seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for replying. As the title says, I am trying to count decimal places. The `LEN()` seems to work when it takes numbers as input.

Comment: This happens because, while Excel shows you the rounded number, internally it's measuring the length of the full representation when the number is converted to a string -- and since Excel's binary floating point is not accurate in decimals, you'll get the `LEN` of `0.000738999999995826`, which is 20. `LEN(0.000739)` "works", but `100.000739 - 100` is not actually the same value as `0.000739` -- try showing the result of `(100.000739 - 100) - 0.000739`.

Answer (score 0):

LEN returns the length of a string. A1-INT(A1) is a number, not a string.

Try

```
=T(A1-INT(A1)
```

and compare that with

```
=LEN(T(A1-INT(A1)))
```

That way you can see what value LEN is really using.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
=LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)
```

if you have some integers in column A, then you will get an error as FIND will fail to find the decimal point. You can resolve that by first testing if the value in column A is an integer, and returning "0" in that case, like so:

```
=IF(A1=INT(A1),0,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula to return the number of decimal places
=ROUNDDOWN((LEN(CELL)/2 + 0.5), 0)

Comment: Testing this in Excel it is clear that this answer does not work.